# docker compose file not working : Additional property web is not allowed

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, stack, docker-swarm

Trying to get the docker-compose.yml working from the getting started tutorials
I have a docker image that I'm using docker compose to start a container with. What's confusing is that after I start the container and I make edits to the database and close the container down (docker-compose down), the database changes are persistent (which is what I want)

```
 **version: "3.8"
    services:
      db:
        image: mysql:latest
        volumes:
          - type: volume
            source: dbmysql
            target: /var/lib/mysql
        networks:
          - webappnet
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
          MYSQL_USER: wordpress
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
          MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
        deploy:
          replicas: 1
          update_config:
            delay: 5s
            parallelism: 1
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
          placement:
            constraints: [node.hostname == master]
    web:
      depends_on:
        - db
      image: wordpress:latest
      volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: dbweb
          target: /var/wwwh/html
      networks:
        - webappnet
      environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
        WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      deploy:
        replicas: 1
        update_config:
          delay: 10s
        restart_policy:
          condition: on-failure
        placement:
          constraints: [node.hostname == slave1]      
    volumes:
      dbmysql:
      dbweb:      
    networks:
      webappnet:
        driver: overlay
        name: webappname**
```

Getting this error:

```
    Additional property web is not allowed
```

What have I typed in wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. "web" is at the same level as "services" but needs to be at the same level as "db".